# res/drawable not refreshing file name change && R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable

So this is slightly different from all the other R cannot be resolved issues in that I had my app working right before and is *not* caused by some main syntax issue as far as I can tell...all I did was an image name change:

1. Change the picture file name in all my res/drawable folders from
   someImageLarge to someImage via Windows
2. Do a find/replace for someImageLarge to someImage (eg R.drawable.someImage)
3. Refresh res DIR in Eclipse (no name change shown, still had old name)
4. Clean project (in the hopes it might update R)

So in theory, my code should work since I updated the code properly as well, so how do I get my code to compile again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a name like R.drawable.some_image . Only lower-case letters are allowed in the resources.

Comment: I've changed renamed in Windows and did find/replace for some_image but am still running into the same issue...refreshing res still doesn't reflect file name changes

Comment: Maybe it will work with: **Right-Click > Refactor > Rename...** This helped me more than one time...

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Problems` window in Eclipse.

An `AAPT` error will be shown there, which means your resources could not be built, thus `R` cannot be found. The console might give you even more information.

Choose a lower-case name for your drawable resource. `AAPT` has problems with upper-case file names.

Comment: I've changed renamed in Windows and did find/replace for some_image but am still running into the same issue...refreshing res still doesn't reflect file name changes

Comment: Then you have other issues as well. What does the Console view say?

Comment: Did you clean your project again?

Comment: Console says nothing and I get the "Please fix errors before running application" message. And yes, I re-cleaned my project

Comment: Issue was fixed by  **Right-Click > Refactor > Rename...**

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this kind of issue before, If your `Eclipse` is highlighting the `import R...` something (indicating what have caused the error) then just remove it(the `import R...`), cause it could be the path has not changed though you already renamed the images. Then refresh, or clean your project again.